# Why is $\frac{d^2x^{\mu}}{d\lambda^2}=0$ not a tensorial equation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, covariance

In flat space, the motion of freely falling particles given by the parametrized path $x^\mu(\lambda)$ is given by the geodesic equation
$$\frac{d^2x^{\mu}}{d\lambda^2}=0.$$
Why is this not a tensorial equation?

From my understanding, $\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$ is a $(1,0)$ tensor $A^\mu$ and $\frac{dA^\mu}{d\lambda}$ is taking the difference of a tensor, i.e. $dA^\mu$ and dividing with a scalar $d\lambda.$ This means that $\frac{dA^\mu}{d\lambda} \equiv\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} $ is a tensor.

Comment: To be tensorial it has to transform appropriately.

Comment: It's a difference of tensors evaluated at _different_ points - That's why its not a tensor. To make it a tensor, you have to take the tensor at the point $x^\mu ( \lambda + d \lambda)$, parallel transport it to the point $x^\mu(\lambda)$ and then take a difference. The parallel transport part of this process introduces a connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A^\mu(\lambda) \equiv \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$ are the **components** of a $(1,0)$-tensor $\mathbf A = A^\mu \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right|_{x(\lambda)}$ attached to the point $x(\lambda)$.  The derivative $\frac{d}{d\lambda} \mathbf A$ involves computing the difference between two tensors - $\mathbf A(\lambda + d\lambda)$ and $\mathbf A(\lambda)$ - which are attached to different points, namely $x(\lambda+d\lambda)$ and $x(\lambda)$.

This ability is provided by the connection $\Gamma$.  Explicitly, we have that
$$\mathbf A(\lambda+d\lambda) \simeq \mathbf A(\lambda) + \left(\frac{dA^\mu}{d\lambda} + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu \alpha} \frac{dA^\nu}{d\lambda} \frac{dA^\alpha}{d\lambda}\right) d\lambda\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right|_{x(\lambda)}$$
and so
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} \mathbf A = \left(\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\lambda^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\lambda}\right) \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\right|_{x(\lambda)}$$
In cartesian coordinates, the connection components $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\alpha}$ all vanish and so $\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\lambda^2}$ transforms like a tensor *provided* that you remain in Cartesian coordinates (i.e. you only perform Lorentz transformations), but if you want an object which transforms properly under *general* coordinate transformations then you'll need to include the $\Gamma$ term.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation will only be a tensor if you are in flat Minkowski spacetime with an affine coordinate system. The reason is that the partial derivative is simply not a tensor.

The velocity of a point moving along a curve $x^\mu (\lambda)$ is given by
$$\mathbf{v}=v^\mu\mathbf{e}_\mu = \frac{\text{d} x^\mu}{\text{d}\lambda}\mathbf{e}_\mu$$
and the acceleration is obtained by differentiating the above expression once more. There is no reason, in general, that the basis $\mathbf{e}_\mu$ is constant. The problem in your understanding is that $v^\mu$ is *not* a tensor; $\mathbf{v}=v^\mu\mathbf{e}_\mu$ is. A tensor always comprises *both* components and basis. You can't simply take the components $v^\mu$ and call them a tensor. Therefore, $\text{d}v^\mu/\text{d}\lambda$ is not a tensor; $\text{d}\mathbf{v}/\text{d}\lambda$ is.

As such, your equation will only be a tensor if the basis is constant everywhere (such that its derivative is zero everywhere), which is an affine coordinate system.